# Using SoundJS with node webkit and local MP3 files

Tags: node.js, webkit, soundjs

Has anyone used soundjs within a node webkit application using local mp3 files?

Can it be done? If so I will keep researching.

I have test apps that work through a browser (Chrome) playing my MP3 library with it but I cannot update my local library within javascript in an HTML5 page in my browser. As browsers block that.

So to get persistence I moved to a local app with node webkit and can do everything I want except successfully install soundjs.

Can it be done? If so I will keep researching.

The soundjs I am talking about is the one at http://createjs.com/Docs/SoundJS/modules/CreateJS.html

not the soundjs you install with npm. That is a module to access Soundcloud.

PS this is hobby fun stuff not real world stuff.
PPS I am working on Windows 8.1 just to make it harder!